What causes the CouplingBetweenObjects error?
I am making a filament dashboard and when I added the filter
            ->filters([
                Tables\Filters\SelectFilter::make('role_id')
                    ->options(
                        Role::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->label('Role'),
            ])

and tried to commit it using GitHub Desktop I got the following error:
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\filament\app\Filament\Resources\UserResource.php:18 CouplingBetweenObjects The class UserResource has a coupling between objects value of 14. Consider to reduce the number of dependencies under 13.

My full UserResource:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\UserResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Resources\UserResource\RelationManagers;
use App\Models\User;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Guest;

class UserResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = User::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->label('Name')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                    ->label('Email')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('password')
                    ->label('Password')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('guest_id')
                    ->label('Guest')
                    ->options(
                        Guest::all()->pluck('ip', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('role_id')
                    ->label('Role')
                    ->options(
                        Role::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->required(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email_verified_at')
                    ->label('Email Verified')
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('role.name')
                    ->label('Role')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('guest.ip')
                    ->label('Guest')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('google_id')
                    ->sortable(),
            ])
            ->filters([
                Tables\Filters\SelectFilter::make('role_id')
                    ->options(
                        Role::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
                    )
                    ->label('Role'),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListUsers::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateUser::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditUser::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}

I'm unsure where the error came from but I assume it's caused by the role filter I added. But is there something wrong with the filter I made or did it exceed a limit?


The error is not a "git" error but rather git for windows software
